# SQL Server 2012 - cannot Import XML with xmlns into table

Tags: sql-server, openxml, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to import some nodes into a sql server table from an xml file with ns

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetSellerTransactionsResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2019-08-03T17:51:45.081Z</Timestamp>
    ...
</GetSellerTransactionsResponse>
```

with this query:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLwithOpenXML
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents' )
insert into Users (EIASToken,Email, UserID,RegistrationDate)
SELECT distinct EIASToken,Email, UserID,RegistrationDate
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'GetSellerTransactionsResponse/TransactionArray/Transaction/Buyer')
WITH 
(
    EiasToken[nvarchar](100) 'EIASToken',
    Email[nvarchar](100) 'Email',
    UserID [nvarchar](100) 'UserID',
    RegistrationDate [datetime] 'RegistrationDate',
    Name [nvarchar] (100) 'BuyerInfo/ShippingAddress/Name'
)
where EIASToken not in (select EIASToken from Users)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
```

I solved in this way, creating a name for xmlns (ebl) and adding `@xmlns` as third parameter to `sp_xml_preparedocument` and then adding ebl: to all nodes and subnodes and removing the `;WITH XMLNAMESPACES` statement:

```
SET @xmlns = '<GetSellerTransactionsResponse xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" />'
SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLwithOpenXML

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML, @xmlns

insert into Users (EIASToken,Email, UserID,RegistrationDate,Name)
SELECT distinct EIASToken,Email, UserID,RegistrationDate,Name
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'ebl:GetSellerTransactionsResponse/ebl:TransactionArray/ebl:Transaction/ebl:Buyer')
WITH 
(
EiasToken[nvarchar](100) 'ebl:EIASToken',
Email[nvarchar](100) 'ebl:Email',
UserID [nvarchar](100) 'ebl:UserID',
RegistrationDate [datetime] 'ebl:RegistrationDate',
Name [nvarchar] (100) 'ebl:BuyerInfo/ebl:ShippingAddress/ebl:Name'
)
where EIASToken not in (select EIASToken from Users)
```

but I'm quite sure there's a way to avoid all that `ebl:`
can somebody suggest the solution?
Thanks

```
-----------------
```

Following the suggestion of marc_s I tried to build the queries with XQuery (actually not using `@XML.query`)

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents' )
INSERT INTO dbo.Sales 
    (...) 
SELECT
    ...
FROM @XML.nodes('//OrderArray/Order/TransactionArray/Transaction') as O(X)
```

and

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents' )
INSERT INTO dbo.Sales 
    (...) 
SELECT
    ...
FROM @XML.nodes('//OrderArray/Order') as O(X)
CROSS APPLY O.X.nodes('//TransactionArray/Transaction') as I(X)
WHERE O.X.value('(TransactionArray/Transaction/TransactionID/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(70)')=I.X.value('(TransactionID/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(70)')
```

Firsts solution returned the same number of records, while second is missing some 10%.
But biggest issue is on performances:

Parsing the same 12MB XML with 1237 "Records" I got the following results:

```
OPENXML
(1237 rows affected)
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 687 ms,  elapsed time = 986 ms.
```

-

```
XQuery without Cross Apply
(1237 rows affected)
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 14.106.641 ms,  elapsed time = 7.788.378 ms.
```

-

```
XQuery with Cross Apply
(1134 rows affected)
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 1.661.968 ms,  elapsed time = 1.668.166 ms.
```

Therefore the `OPENXML` Solution is the only one reasonable, or have I made some mistakes or should use `@XML.query()` ?

Comment: Don't use the old, deprecated `OPENXML` approach - you should really use the XQuery functionality built into SQL Server from version 2005 and up. That definitely supports the `XMLNAMESPACES` approach

Comment: Thanks marc_s for your suggestion: I tried to build a couple of Queries with XQuery, but as you can see above I got "strange" results, mainly with reference to performances.. Thanks for any consideration.